# AWS - ECS EC2 cluster running container with ALB and more than 5 ports forwarded - in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, load-balancing, amazon-ecs

I am running an ECS cluster with about 20 containers. I have a big monolith application running on 1 container which requires to listen on 10 ports.

However AWS requires to have a max of 5 load balancer target group links in an ECS Service.

Any ideas how to overcome this (if possible)? Here's what I've tried:

1. Defining 10+ target groups with 1 listener each. Doesn't work since AWS requires a max of 5 load balancer definitions in the aws_ecs_service - for info - here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html as stated in the 2nd bullet under "Service load balancing considerations"
2. Defining 10+ listeners with 1 target group - however all listeners forward to a single port on the container...
3. Tried without specifying  port in the load_balancer definition in aws_ecs_service, however AWS complains for missing argument
4. Tried without specifying port in the aws_lb_target_group, however AWS complains that target type is "ip", so port is required...

Here's my current code:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service_app" {
    name = "my_service_name"
    cluster = var.ECS_CLUSTER_ID
    task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.task_my_app.arn
    desired_count = 1
    force_new_deployment = true

...

   load_balancer { # Note: I've stripped the for_each to simplify reading
        target_group_arn = var.tga
        container_name = var.n
        container_port = var.p
    }
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group" "tg_mytg" {
    name = "Name"
    protocol = "HTTP"
    port = 3000
    target_type = "ip"
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}
resource "aws_lb_listener" "ls_3303" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.my_lb.id
  port = "3303"
  protocol = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.tg_mytg.arn
  }
}
```

...

Comment: Maybe you could add proxy services (, e.g. nginx) for different ports? So your LB would target proxies which would forward to the monoloyth. ECS Service discovery could be used for referencing the monolyth container.

Comment: Alternative is to run your own docker on EC2 instance, not using ECS. You shouldn't have problems opening 20 ports on an instance.